# Kendo UI custom grid popup editor window only opens once

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to use a custom window as popup editor of a Kendo UI Grid. Its content will be complex with search fields and a grid to display search results. To do that, I don't want to use the Kendo template mechanism but a real popup window.

While doing tests with custom editor I faced an issue. Even with a very basic and simple scenario (just the create command), I'm only able to open the editor once. The second time I get an error, the editor doesn't show up anymore and the grid becomes empty.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<div id="main-content">

    <div id="custom-window">
    </div>

    <table id="my-table-grid">
    </table>

</div>
```

The JavaScript part :

```
function openCustomWindow(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   myWindow.center().open();
}

function editorWindowClosed(e) {  
    myGrid.cancelRow(); 
}

var myWindow = $("#custom-window").kendoWindow({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            title: "Test",
            visible: false,
            close: editorWindowClosed
        }).data("kendoWindow");

var dummyDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
    {
        schema : {
            model : {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    postion: { type: "number"},
                    name: { type: "string"},
                }
            }
        }
    });

dummyDataSource.add({postion: 1, name: "gswin"});

var myGrid = $("#my-table-grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: dummyDataSource,
                toolbar: [ {
                    name: "create",
                    text: "Create"
                } ],
                editable: {
                    mode: "popup",
                    window: {
                        animation: false,
                        open: openCustomWindow,
                    }
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: "postion",
                        title: "Postion"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "name",
                        title: "Name"
                    }
               ]
            }).data("kendoGrid");
```

The error message in the JavaScript console :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of
>   undefinedut.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend.cancelRow @
>   kendo.all.min.js:29ut.ui.DataBoundWidget.extend.addRow @
>   kendo.all.min.js:29(anonymous function) @
>   kendo.all.min.js:29jQuery.event.dispatch @
>   jquery-2.1.3.js:4430jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle @
>   jquery-2.1.3.js:4116

And finally a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gswin/p4c37tj3/) to show what I'm doing. (The popup is empty because I just want to fix the open / close mechanism before going any further)

I don't understand why I get this error, I expected to be able to open / close the popup as many time as I wanted. The default editor popup is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the approach in my previous answer solved my issue but is causing another issue. The grid becomes editable but in the default mode (which is "inline").

Doing this

```
editable: "popup",
edit: openCustomWindow
```

has fixed this other issue but is now displaying 2 popups.

I finally succeeded to hide the default popup and only show my custom popup but it ended with the orginal issue described in initial question...

Considering all those informations I arrived to the conclusion that working with a custom popup window is definitely not an option. I'll start working with teamplates instead.

Another solution would have been to use a template to override the toolbar with a custom "Add" button and use a custom command for edition. But at this point I consider that too "tricky".

Comment: But this seems to be the best, working answer.  Having to individually create the kendo window objects and using e.preventDefault() was the only way I was able to get that edit function to stop initiliazing the windows twice.

Comment: How do you pass parameters from an editable grid-row into a template popup?

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleague found the solution (thanks to him).

Actually this piece of code

```
        editable: {
            mode: "popup",
            window: {
                animation: false,
                open: openCustomWindow,
            }
        }
```

is designed to configure the default popup...

The right way to use a custom popup is the following :

```
       editable :true,
       edit: openCustomWindow,
```

With this approach it's also better to use

```
function editorWindowClosed(e) {  
    myGrid.cancelChanges(); 
}
```

Instead of

```
function editorWindowClosed(e) {  
    myGrid.cancelRow(); 
}
```

Working [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gswin/p4c37tj3/9/)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent Kendo UI custom grid popup editor window, define the editable property:

```
editable: 
    {
        mode: "popup",
        window: {               
            animation: false,
            open: updateRowEventHandler
        }
    } // skip edit property
```

Then paste preventDefault() at the beginning of the handler:

```
function updateRowEventHandler(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); //
```